# 1700s term for "a technology"

Tags: word-choice, history

Today, I could use "a technology" to mean a mechanical or industrial development:

> The most important transportation technology during that era was the railroad.

According to [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=technology), "technology" in this usage isn't known to occur before 1859.

**What term would someone use in the 1700s for a technology?**

For example, Thomas Jefferson might have referred to the printing press, the steam engine, and the thermometer as "three ___s".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think they might have been called ***inventions***

> a device, contrivance, or process originated after study and experiment. <sub><sup>[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/invention)</sup></sub>

Here's an example from [*THE SCOTS MAGAZINE OR GENERAL REPOSITORY OF LITERATURE, HISTORY, AND POLITICS*](http://books.google.com.my/books?id=h9cPAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA106&dq=%22invention%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=brUcVKCSEtGwogTlt4CICA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22invention%22&f=false) from 1799:

> AS many people entertain inaccurate ideas concerning that moſt important and intereſting invention the Teleſcope, permit me briefly to ſtate the facts ...

Comment: Why are some s ſ but not all?

Comment: @NeilKirk- **Short answer:** That's how it was in the book.  **Longer answer:** The long s was used in ligatures in various languages.  When a font containing the long s is used, German typographic rules require the common s to be used when it occurs singly at the end of a syllable, while the long s is used at the beginning of a syllable (more detailed rules are given for other cases). -Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s)

Comment: I read that as moft and interefting...

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps the term *[device](http://books.google.com/books?id=wDPlngEACAAJ&dq=%22device%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rZ0cVPyWI8SvyATFgIKQCQ&ved=0CFAQ6AEwCQ)*. It appears in a patent signed by Jefferson

> Letter of Patent for a Grain Separating Device, Signed by Thomas Jefferson and James Madison. Dec. 21, 1803. DS, 3 Pp. (1 Folio Pc.).

Comment: Yes, or "engine"

Comment: @ColinFine: A thermometer, an *engine*?

Comment: I was confused, initially I thought you were suggesting "patent" The same word is repeated in the quote, but as that didn't make much sense, I read more carefully and saw your suggestion is **device** which definitely sounds better.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Good point. Adjusted the link. Thanks.

Comment: @Cerberus: certainly, though maybe not by the 1700's. The OED s.v. engine, meaning 5 ("A tool, implement, or simple mechanical device. Now arch.") has 16th century examples _" in the stokkis or sic uther ingine."_ and _"Ropes and other yngynes."_

Comment: @ColinFine: Oh, cool. I suppose the word originally meant "something ingenious", so that makes sense. What are or is stokkis, by the way? All I can find it "swords" in a source from/about Scotland. Something made of/with sticks?

Comment: No, it means the [stocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stocks).

Answer (score 2):

Probably the term [mechanisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanization) conveyed the idea of technology development at that time:

> - mechanisation or mechanisation (BE) is the process of doing work with machinery.
> - The Industrial Revolution started mainly with textile machinery, such as the spinning jenny (1764) and water frame (1768).
> - Demand for metal parts used in textile machinery led to the invention of many machine tools in the late 1700s until the mid-1800s.

Source: www.en.wikipedia.org

Comment: So someone like Jefferson would refer to the printing press as "a mechanisation"?

Comment: Certainly not. The earliest attribution for _mechanization_ in the OED is 1839, and that includes the phrase _the mechanization of man_, so it clearly means "the process of turning man into a machine".

Comment: Perhaps you mean *mechanism*?

Answer (score 0):

[Technical was a word in the mid 1700s](http://books.google.com/books?id=bXsCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PP849#v=onepage&q&f=false), btw. Source: A dictionary of the English Language by Samuel Johnson. It might not be unheard of to be a *technical device*.

Comment: In that source, Johnson considers "technical" to be an adjective.  That means Jefferson wouldn't call the printing press, steam engine, and thermometer "three technicals".

Comment: True, but then it'd not be unreasonable to be a technical device as otherwise proposed.

Comment: If you're suggesting "technical device", rather than "technical", go ahead and make that your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be using the terms technical and technology in the normal meaning.  An 'ology' is a science or body of knowledge.  There trend in the last few years in marketing to call products technology.  Meaning my iPhone is a field of science.

Ie.  Technology, the field of science and body of knowledge related to skills and TECHniques was used to create a product which is a device.

Comment: This is not only a trend in the last few years.  [Here's an example](http://goo.gl/ID6Nzx) from 1950 of *technologies* being used in the way I'm using it.

Comment: @Joe You're not using it wrongly, but the market use of technology usually isn't at the same level as 'dentistry' or 'high pressure steam engine'. The technology in an iPhone is mainly silicon integration, soft core, capacitive sensing, toughened glass, optics, C-family programming languages. The iPhone isn't a technology in the same was as 'high pressure steam engines', nor are most of the things touted as such - the real technologies in the latest iPhone are mostly 20+ years old, it's a device containing refined examples of those technologies.